# Get token from Laravel in Nuxt 3 authorization process using sidebase/nuxt-auth and GoogleProvider

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I'm using `nuxt 3.2.3` with `@sidebase/nuxt-auth 0.5.0-rc.0` for authorization.

I defined Google Provider this way:

```
...
GoogleProvider.default({
  clientId: 'secret.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  clientSecret: 'secret',
  token: {
    url: "https://api.example.com/api/auth/socialite/google"
  }
})
...
```

So I added `token` option as it is defined here: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/oauth#token-option

And also jwt callback:

```
...
async jwt({ token, account }) {
  if (account) {
    token.jwt = account.id_token
  }
  return token
}
...
```

Everything works fine like Google authorization and so on, but in the process of authorization I would expect to make an API request to retrieve an access_token from my Laravel application. There are some `access_token` and `id_token` in `account` parameter, but those are not from my application.

I did the same with Nuxt 2 few years ago with some different settings and it worked:

```
...
google: {
  clientId: 'secret.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  clientSecret: 'secret',
  responseType: 'code',
  codeChallengeMethod: '',
  endpoints: {
    token: 'https://api.example.com/api/auth/socialite/google'

  },
  token: {
    property: 'access_token',
  }
}
...
```

Am I using the `token` option the right way?

Answer (score 1):

After reading [this article](https://arunoda.me/blog/add-auth-support-to-a-next-js-app-with-a-custom-backend) I found out the solution for my effort to connect Nuxt and nuxt-auth with separate API server.

The token from my backend application is possible to obtain using `signIn` Callback. No need to use `token` option in Google Provider.